# reCaptcha locked me out of my Drupal website. Unable to login

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-modules, recaptcha

I am developing a website using Drupal 6 and I enable the reCaptcha module to check its functionality. It now redirects me to the google recaptaha page : `https://www.google.com/recaptcha/admin/create`
I am not sure of the exact process and I have not set the keys yet, which I can do only if I can get access to my site. I am not able to login and even disable the module. Based on the suggestion on Drupal forum, I accessed the database and disable the module from the  `system` table but I still get the redirection. I cleared all the cache tables in the MySQL database but still the same. What should i do to get access and disable the module? Is there any good tutorial/video to set the `reCapthca` module?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:
 1. Clear your browser cache and cookies
 2. Check with different browser

Answer (score 0):

backup the recaptcha row from the system table.
delete the recaptcha row in the system table.
That should disable the module.

if still give the same error please access your drupal website cron job url
the link will look like

http://www.yoursite.com/cron.php